# Can an electrostatic shield provide protection from the Van Allen belt?

Tags: physics, radiation, van-allen-belt

Would an electrostatic shield provide enough protection for a crewed space craft to survive in the Van Allen belt for more then an hour?

Comment: Interesting; a few hundred kilovolts negative certainly might help *somewhat*but it's hard to say how much.

Comment: I just noticed that you've deleted your question. I think it's a good question and I hope you can either undelete or post something similar soon!

Comment: I imagine generating electrostatic potentials of >100 kV on an object that is not extremely conductive would cause arcing and ablation.  Generally things in space should be conductive so charge doesn't build up leading to electrostatic discharge and ablative loss of material.  This can happen for potentials as low as a few kV so >100 kV would likely be asking for trouble.  If not, it would be a nightmare trying to stop the plasma currents such a potential would attract/cause.